vue vitest - vue-router spy is not being called
I am writing a test suite for my vue 3 application using vitest and vue test utils. When the vue component is mounted, it calls its own init method, which in turn initializes a store to make a post request to an API, and return a value. Based on the returned value, the vue component is then expected to call router.replace
The problem is, my test suite fails when it expects router.replace to be called. I can verify that the first test expectation (store.init is called) succeeds, but not the test for router.replace.
Also, I am not seeing the console.logs on the test terminal's console screen, but when I manually test using a real browser, everything works fine.
Here is my test suite:
import { describe, test, beforeEach, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('MyComponent initializes', () => {
    let router
    let store
    let wrapper

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const pinia = createPinia()
        setActivePinia(pinia)
        router = createRouter({
            history: createWebHistory(),
            routes: routes
        })
        store = useMyStore()
    })

    describe('Redirect according to appStatus', () => {
        test('when appStatus is 1', async() => {
            router.push('/test')
            await router.isReady()
            const routerReplaceSpy = vi.spyOn(router, 'replace')
            const storeInitSpy = vi.SpyOn(store, 'init')

            wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
                global: {
                    plugins: [router]
                }
            })

            expect(storeInitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce() // passes
            expect(routerReplaceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce() // fails
        })
    })
})

And this is the vue component MyComponent:
const route = useRoute()
const init = async () => {
    const appStatus = await myStore.init(route.params.transactionId)
    console.log(appStatus)
    if (appStatus === '1') {
        router.replace({ name: 'endpoint1' })
        console.log('router.replace call success')
    }
}

onMounted(async () => {
    init()
})

Here is a snippet of the store's implementation:
const init = async (transactionId) => {
    const resData = await axios.post('<myPOSTendpoint>', transactionId)
    return resData.appStatus
}


There's a race condition. You need to mock store init or axios request and use something like flushPromises before asserting
